# Render an object so that it is pure black with zero transparency

Tags: rendering, materials, eevee-render-engine

I have rendered images that I'm going to post-process. Some objects in the scene are supposed to act as markers that the post-processing script will try to locate based on the pixel value being pure black (ie argb: #ff000000).

I created a principal BSDF material with zero specular etc, and applied it to a small cube object, but when it's rendered, you can see the output pixels around the edges are of varying shades / opacities:

[image]

Is there any way to make a material that'll render pure black with zero opacity?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like your small cube is really small compared to the rendering resolution, so the contours will be anti-aliased. The center is pure black, though...

Comment: maybe an Emission instead of a Principled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **no shader at all**.  Empty socket on surface.

[image]

You could also use *Cryptomatte* to generate a pixel perfect mask if the anti-aliasing around the edges is troublesome.

[image]

[image]

You can clearly see the staircase here representing every pixel where the object could be sampled.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend trying a Diffuse shader instead of a Principled BSDF. A diffuse shader essentially adds 'pigment' to a material, without any kind of gloss, specularity, opacity, etc.

However judging by your screenshot I believe the grey variations you are  getting are a result of anti-aliasing related to the resolution of your render (and the relative size of the black object), not the shader. The grey variations appear to be a blend of the pure black from your shader, and the grey background.

I would maybe try increasing the resolution of your render (try 200/400%?) and maybe turning off denoising to see if that improves matters.

[image]

[image]